# Create session make the iOS LinkedIn app crash

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I am trying to get loggedin from LinkedIn using the native SDK but when I perform the following code the app LinkedIn app opens and crashes.

```
    let permissions = [LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION]
    LISDKSessionManager.createSessionWithAuth(permissions, state: "0", showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: { (returnState) -> Void in
        println("Return state : \(returnState)")
    }) { (error) -> Void in
        println("Error : \(error.description)")
    }
```

I have the following trace in the Device logs

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1840d42d8 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x195d500e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1840d4218 +[NSException raise:format:] + 128
3   Foundation                      0x184ef5758 -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithString:] + 132
4   LinkedIn                        0x100a32458 0x1000e0000 + 9774168
5   LinkedIn                        0x100a30d00 0x1000e0000 + 9768192
6   UIKit                           0x188b4cc18 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 692
7   UIKit                           0x188b4c928 -[UIViewController view] + 32
8   UIKit                           0x188e894e0 -[UINavigationController preferredContentSize] + 156
9   UIKit                           0x188e575a4 -[UIPresentationController preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:] + 136
10  UIKit                           0x188e548a0 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 160
11  UIKit                           0x188bd01d4 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 356
12  UIKit                           0x188b40680 _afterCACommitHandler + 536
13  CoreFoundation                  0x18408c2a4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
14  CoreFoundation                  0x184089230 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 360
15  CoreFoundation                  0x184089610 __CFRunLoopRun + 836
16  CoreFoundation                  0x183fb52d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
17  GraphicsServices                0x18da136fc GSEventRunModal + 168
18  UIKit                           0x188bb2f40 UIApplicationMain + 1488
19  LinkedIn                        0x1000f1c1c 0x1000e0000 + 72732
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x1963faa08 start + 4
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the Linkedin app and downloaded it again and it solved the issue.
I guess there is still something to be caught inside LinkedIn app.